# 24 Hour Android app connection with PHP web server

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

My goal is to download some information from a PHP web server. I have created a service to run 24 hours. App start this service using alaram manager class.

```
    Intent ishintent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 2523, ishintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 15000, pintent);
```

AlarmReceiver.class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("local", 0);
        boolean TaskEnabled = settings.getBoolean("taskenabled", false);
        if (!TaskEnabled) {
            Intent myService = new Intent(context, ServiceClass.class);
            context.startService(myService);
        }
    }
}
```

Service class have an AsyncTask which download data from internet using HttpURLConnection.

```
@Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);

            new DownloadInfo().execute("http://example.com/xxx.php");
    }
```

Class DownloadInfo

```
 class DownloadInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            // constants
            try {

                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(30000); // miliseconds
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Charset",  "UTF-8");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + "UTF-8");
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("user", "1111")
                        .appendQueryParameter("pass", "1111");
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();
                line = response.toString();
                return line;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                if (result != null) {

                }
        }
```

I am observing this service from last 53 hours. Service is running fine (Settings>app>Running). I have tried different things to ensure the 24 hour connectivity of app which includes turning WiFi radio off and on, turning my WiFi router on and off, plugging out internet cable from router and then putting it back in. App was working fine. But after 28 hours when I checked my app, I found that app is not downloading data from internet. It seems that app was trying to connect with internet but after time out it downloaded nothing. I have checked the web page which app was trying to access via web browser of android device, it was running fine. I have turned wifi radio off and on and app immediately get connected with internet. Now what I can do to ensure that my app keeps it connection established with web server?

**Update**

AsyncTask download some information which is no more than 160 bytes in form of text. We have poultry business so this information contains new rates of local area.

App starts this service at regular intervals (15 sec) by scheduling task using AlaramManager class.

Comment: Since you are trying to connect to the server 24 hour i.e. periodic task. Why don't you use GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) Network Manager to connect to the server periodically. Your code will try to connect even if there in no internet access in the device which will not happen in GCM. For code example you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/network-manager).

Comment: Thanks for you comment Aawaz, I planned to use GCM and in fact I had started my app with that approach but the problem is that GCM do not respond immediately every time.Some time you send a notification via GCM which recieve to client with a delay of an hour.

Comment: You are welcome.The choice is completely yours. I just tried to insure that you know about GCM Network Manager for scheduling periodic task. Thanks.

Comment: `AsyncTask which download data from internet using HttpURLConnection.`. You did not explain about the data. What should be downloade 24 hours long? You could elaborate on that. How does your app work? How long does one doInBackground take? For every doInBackground you have a new connection. So where are you taking about when you name `24 hours connected` ?

Comment: If the service is running 24 hours then how often would it start an AsyncTask? I only see one started. Please explain what the code should do.

Comment: Thanks for your kind replies, I have updated the question.