# Proper way to use HttpURLConnection

Tags: php, android, hibernate, android-asynctask

*This question is a part of my previous question which is still unanswered. Here you can see it. [24 Hour Android app connection with PHP web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31846657/24-hour-android-app-connection-with-php-web-server)*.

I am using HttpURLConnection to download some text from PHP web page. App use a service to execute AsyncTask at regular intervals. I observe that if mobiles WiFi connects to a router which have no internet than sometimes (not always) application behave in such a way that it is trying to connect internet without having any effect of connection timeout, set while connecting to webpage. Even if internet starts coming again application do nothing and keep trying to connect to internet.

This behavior can also be check of Emulator in a couple of ways. First just turn of your WLAN and wait for 30 minutes and connect again. You will see that HttpURLConnection will keep trying to connect to internet and will never give up and never get connected with internet. If we hibernate windows and starts it again the same behavior can be observed. But it not happened all the time.

I think there is some problem with my method of using HttpURLConnection not with my Service. Please help me with this situation. Here is my source code.

```
class DownloadInfo extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            // constants
            try {

                System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false"); // also checked without this line.

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url[0]).openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setConnectTimeout(30000); // miliseconds
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive"); // also checked with "Connection", "Close"
                connection.setRequestProperty("Charset",  "UTF-8");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + "UTF-8");
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("user", "1111")
                        .appendQueryParameter("pass", "1111");
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(line);
                    response.append('\r');
                }
                rd.close();
               // also tried  is.close(); AND  connection.disconnect();

                line = response.toString();
                return line;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.w("MyApp", "Download Exception : " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                if (result != null) {

                }
        }
```

Comment: `This question is a part of my previous question which is still unanswered`. That is nonsense. You have not even reacted on my questions for more information. It is still an unclear story.

Comment: You use a lot of words where maybe the only thing you want to say is 'I never get a SocketTimeoutException!' ?

Comment: Hibernate? Why are you concerned about your app running on an emulator where windows goes to sleep? Is that what you are talking about? Just use a real device for serious testing.

Comment: Its just a matter of choice that I am using emulator to test application. In the meanwhile I am also testing it on the real device. And I think I had answered your comment.